# WCF Security Message vs Transport speed

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, security

How much slower is Message security typically compared to transport security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to depend on your scenario, but [here are some performance comparisons with benchmarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx).

Comment: You'll have to look at several of them - there isn't one that compares transport to message, but there are transport graphs and message graphs, which will give you a way to compare. Looks like transport security is about 2-3 times faster. Again, this will depend greatly on your scenario, you do your own performance testing.